# Functionality needed by the profiler has been intercepted by another application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, visual-studio, memory, profiling

I am trying to profile a MVC1 web application. The moment I start the profiler in Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate, I get this error message and profiler do not work after that.

```
Functionality needed by the profiler has been intercepted by another application...
```

Googling the same, pointed out that it is generally antivirus or firewall issue.

I have McAfee (v 4-6-0-2292).

Any pointers?

Comment: Perhaps disabling the Antivirus and/or firewall and testing it?